# Extracting only the Double from a firebase snapshot (swift)

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This is my data in firebase:
[image: Firebase data]

override func viewDidLoad() {

```
    database.child("allOrdersTimeline1").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        var mixedArray1 = [:] as [String : Double]
        let salad = (snapshot.value)
        let keyy = snapshot.key
        let valuee = (snapshot.children.allObjects) //as [String : Double])
        
        
        
        

        self.labelWhatLabel.text = ("\(valuee)")
        print("There are \(snapshot.childrenCount) children found")
        print("1")
        print(keyy)
        print("2")
        print(valuee)
        print("3")
        print(salad)
        print("4")
       
        print("Ny test: \(mixedArray1)")
    
        
        
    })
```

No matter what I try, I keep getting the full line (name and time) as such:
[image: Print out in swift]
I can't figure out how to only get the hour/Double with out the name.

(by the way, im very new and this might be very dumb - My sincere apologies.

Comment: Please try to remove the code that isn’t relevant for the question

Comment: I cleaned it up as much as I could. The code which is left, is me trying to get the  firebase data in as two elements. Name as String and hour as Double - so I can use the hours in a list. hope it clarifies a little bit.

Comment: What happens if you do `let salad = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]`?

Comment: Same result, I get both string and double - as one.

Comment: This is totally unrelated to the question but you may want to alter how you're storing the node keys. Node keys must be unique so what happens when you have John Smith and Larry Smith? Also, node keys cannot contain some characters - if you look at your output you can already see that in action `S/U00F8rensen`. So a better way to do that is to use `.childByAutoId` to create the node key and then store the last name and amount as child nodes; it would look like this `some_node/name: Agerskov` and then`/price: 19`

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be looking for:

```
print(snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath:"Agerskov").value)
```

---

If you don't know the keys of the child nodes, you can [loop over `snapshot.children`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#listen_for_value_events) to access the child snapshots:

```
for child in snapshot.children {
  let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
  print(snap.key)
  print(snap.value)
}
```

Also see these results when you search for [`[firebase-realtime-database][swift] loop over children`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfirebase-realtime-database%5D%5Bswift%5D+loop+over+children).

Comment: I had no idea that I could use a loop here! That did it! That was my big issue as I will not know the keys! It solved the problem and bonus, I now know that I can loop within the "snapshot"! Thank you!